# How to use functions if I want to move a word into end of array in PHP?

Tags: php, search, mysqli, push

Hi I have a table like this:

```
id | name
=============================
1  | blue house
-----------------------------
2  | house red
-----------------------------
3  | black house
-----------------------------
4  | car red
-----------------------------
5  | car black with driver
-----------------------------
6  | pink car
-----------------------------
```

I need output like this:

```
Blue house
Red house
Black house
Red car
Black with driver car
Pink car
```

I need 'house' and 'car' move to the end using php logic. I using search and push function but not in the right way. Any help? Thank you :) my code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shop') or die ("Fail");
$sql="select *  from products";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $names = array_search('house','car',$row,true);
        echo ($names[1]." ".$names[0]." ".$names[2]." ".$names[3]."<br>" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be, for example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // explode `$row['name']` by space into 2 parts only
    $parts = explode(' ', $row['name'], 2);
    // if first part is "house" or "car" - output second part and then first
    if ($parts[0] === 'house' || $parts[0] === 'car') {
        echo $parts[1] . ' ' . $parts[0];
    } else {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. but if I want my output first word start with capital letter and other words start with lower letter. how can I do it?

Comment: `ucfirst` or `mb_convert_case`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply done using, `preg_replace()`:

```
//while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { <!-- no longer needed

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//$rows = [['name'=>  'blue house'],['name'=>'car red'], [...]]
$words = ['house','car'];

print_r(preg_replace('/^('.implode('|', $words ).')\s(.+)$/i', '\2 \1', array_column($rows,'name')));
```

Sandbox Code (for testing):

```
$rows = [
    ['name'=>  'blue house'],
    ['name'=>  'house red'],
    ['name'=>  'black house'],
    ['name'=>  'car red'],
    ['name'=>  'car black with driver'],
    ['name'=>  'pink car'],
];

$words = ['house','car'];

print_r(preg_replace('/^('.implode('|', $words ).')\s(.+)$/i', '\2 \1', array_column($rows,'name')));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue house
    [1] => red house
    [2] => black house
    [3] => red car
    [4] => black with driver car
    [5] => pink car
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcdafdda14962fdeff6893a518597cd0335ea081)

For upper casing the first letter simply do this:

```
 print_r( array_map('ucfirst',preg_replace('/^('.implode('|', $words ).')\s(.+)$/i', '\2 \1', array_column($rows,'name'))) );
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue house
    [1] => Red house
    [2] => Black house
    [3] => Red car
    [4] => Black with driver car
    [5] => Pink car
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/830a4ab4deeee6da7015192875435b3d25d9cad1)

Simply use `array_map()` with `ucfirst` as the callback.  Because your getting these from the DB if your concerned with the casing from the source it's easier to lowercase it in the SQL, eg.  `SELECT LOWER(name) as name FROM ...`.  So for example if `Car red` uppercase: it's easier to get it from the DB all in lower, because it will save you from writing a custom callback for `array_map()`.

The Regex:

Search `'/^('.implode('|', $words ).')\s(.+)$/i'` or `'/^(house|car)\s(.+)$/i'`

- `^` Start of string
- `(...)` First capture group

  - `'.implode('|', $words ).'` each word separated by `|` Or eg.`house|car`
- `\s` Space, this is the first word so it should always be followed by one
- `(...)` Second capture group

  - `.+` Match anything
- `$` Match end of string
- `\i` Case insensitive flag

Replace  `'\2 \1'`, simply flip the capture groups around.

So basically we are matching any items in the array that start with one of the words in our word list and followed by a space and some more words.  Then we replace those matches with the remaining part first, and the first word that we matched last (effectively flipping them around).

The other things I changed here is you can pull the whole result set, then use array column to get just the `name` column.  In `PDO` I could do it with `PdoStatement::fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` and not need array column, but I haven't used MySqli in a long time. So this was the only way I could think of.

One last thing, if this is all you need from the DB, then make sure to select only the `name` field.  This can improve performance because less data is being transferred from the DB to PHP etc...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $arr=[
        'blue house',
        'house red',
        'black house',
        'car red',
        'car black with driver',
        'pink car'
    ];

    $move=['house','car'];

    foreach( $arr as $i => $row ){
        $elements=explode( ' ', $row );
        foreach( $move as $word ){
            if( in_array( $word, $elements ) ){
                $pos=array_search( $word, $elements );
                $elements[]=array_splice( $elements, $pos, 1 )[0];
            }
        }
        $arr[ $i ]=ucfirst( implode( ' ', $elements ) );
    }

    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($arr,true));
```

The above will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue house
    [1] => Red house
    [2] => Black house
    [3] => Red car
    [4] => Black with driver car
    [5] => Pink car
)
```

or, with a recordset:

```
$move=['house','car'];

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $elements=explode( ' ', $row['name'] );
    foreach( $move as $word ){
        if( in_array( $word, $elements ) ){
            $pos=array_search( $word, $elements );
            $elements[]=array_splice( $elements, $pos, 1 );
        }
        echo ucfirst( implode( ' ', $elements ) );
    }

}
```